# When is it appropriate to close a question that appears like it will never be answered?

Tags: discussion

In a quest to answer all unanswered questions on Craft CMS Stack Exchange, I'm reading some fairly ambiguous questions.  They definitely qualify as questions, so the issue is not that they are off-topic or bad.  They just seem to have passed their time and will probably sit unanswered forever because when you read them you think: "Hey, that will probably be unanswered forever."

Here are some examples:

[Unable to access login page or my website](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/unable-to-access-login-page-or-my-website)
The poster mentions they will look into something 5 months ago, a Craft CMS SE user follows up, and the question remains untouched.

[Uploaded file was empty](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/uploaded-file-was-empty)
A very specific server error seems to be occurring for this user, a specific follow up question is asked 4 months ago, and the user provides no more info.

[Cache not invalidating when new entry is created](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/cache-not-invalidating-when-new-entry-is-created)
A Craft CMS SE user followed up for more info and the poster makes a comment that P&T looked into it and couldn't recreate the issue (less than a month ago).

It feels wrong to just delete these as some poor developer could someday stumble upon a similar thing and be given hope when they find some other poor developer with the same issue.  But, they mostly feel like they just clutter up search results with partial conversations where the person with the primary information to help make the answer helpful has disappeared or given up placing the burden of defining and answering the question on the poor, casual OCD Stack Exchange member.

What are best practices around these types of questions?  I'm accepting that there could be valid "unanswered" questions.  But feel these begin to fall in the category of "orphaned questions".

Comment: This is a great question. I don't have the answer, but I made noises in each of your examples just to see if the posts could be nudged out of limbo.

Comment: Maybe some unwritten "if it feels abandoned and has no reply from the OP for 6 months, its fair game to close" rule of thumb?

Comment: This thread brought up [another question that's been bothering me...](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/114/45)

Answer (score 1):

Great question... I suspect that there's no single universal solution for all of these tickets.

I think Matt has the right idea... Nudge the OP, see if the situation ever evolved. On 2 of those 3 questions, Matt was able to get the OP to respond with some sort of update (even if it didn't provide much additional information).

If nudging the OP seems fruitless, then see if there's a legitimate reason to close the ticket.

If it **seems like a bug report**, and no one else has mentioned having the same problem, then it's probably either (A) an issue which has been patched in a newer version of Craft, or (B) some user error in either their code or server configuration. In these cases, I vote to **close as a bug report**.